# How to solve raise ValueError("columns must have matching element counts") ValueError: columns must have matching element counts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

a,b,c,d, and e are lists and they are of the same length

```
print(len(a),len(b),len(c),len(d),len(e))
```

results to:

```
2100,2100,2100,2100,2100

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a,'b':b,'c':c,'d':d,'e':e})

df = df.explode(['c', 'd', 'e'],ignore_index=True)

df = df.fillna('')

df.to_csv("sampledata.csv")
```

This shows the  error:

```
df = df.explode(['c', 'd', 'e'],ignore_index=True)
raise ValueError("columns must have matching element counts")
ValueError: columns must have matching element counts
```

Why is this showing error since they have all the same count?

Comment: df.explode() takes multiples columns above pandas 1.30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
df.set_index(['a', 'b']).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
```

Comment: This does not answer the original question. Why is his example wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have items of different lengths in one of your `c, d, e` lists.

For instance, let's look at c, and assume that the content is:

```
[[1,2],
 [1,2],
 [1,2,3],
 [1,2]]
```

The third row where you have an extra value (3) than "usual" will cause the error.

Comment: So, how do you solve such cases?

Comment: @Vitalis .. I verify the length of the sublists/strings before the process.

Comment: @Vitalis, this could be the issue in some cases, but the OP says the lists "are of the same length"?